# How many pixels is the screen (maxized window)

Tags: javascript, web, pixel

Is there any international standard to get the pixels of a screen in a maxized browser window?

Comment: If you're using fluid/liquid layout techniques, it shouldn't matter much, if at all. I don't want to have to browse your site with my web browser *maximized* to have an optimal viewing experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None standards like that exist. You can only assume basing on statistics, what is the lowest popular resolution and accomodate to that. Current;y 1024px screen width for desktop OSs is pretty much it.

You still need to substract some pixels for browser GUI objects (like scrollbars for example). Since the size of these items depends on the OS/browser/browser settings used, this number can vary.

Bottom line: there is no standard.

Comment: Nonsense. Every browser (and operating system) has a different amount of user interface/window chrome that shrinks the viewable area. You still can't assume 1024 pixels.

Comment: Did I write 'screen width' in to small letters? For clarity I'll add you comment though.